# Converting NSArray to NSString crashes?

Tags: xcode, json, crash, nsstring, nsarray

Trying to get a label to show the data pulled from some JSON...

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSError *myError = nil;
        NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonresponse         options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
        NSArray *results =  [res objectForKey:@"current_observation"];
        NSArray *cur = [results valueForKey:@"weather"];
        NSArray *tmp = [results valueForKey:@"temp_f"];
        NSString * tmpstring = [[tmp valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
        temp.text = tmpstring;
    }
```

When it runs that code, it spits this out...

```
2013-01-31 15:38:03.319 Places[4659:907] -[__NSCFString componentsJoinedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5680d0
2013-01-31 15:38:03.321 Places[4659:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString componentsJoinedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5680d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x32b3e3e7 0x3a82f963 0x32b41f31 0x32b4064d 0x32a98208 0x413b 0x3347a915 0x333ba769 0x333ba685 0x3281b64f 0x3281ad33 0x32843013 0x32a84acd 0x32843473 0x327a7461 0x32b138f7 0x32b1315d 0x32b11f2f 0x32a8523d 0x32a850c9 0x3666333b 0x349a12b9 0x20c9 0x2050)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure that `[tmp valueForKey:@"description"]` returns an NSArray, it rather looks as if it returns a NSString in the error msg

Answer (score 2):

`-description` is a method inherited from NSObject and part of the NSObject protocol; it returns a `NSString *` with some description of the object. All classes can override it to return an arbitrary NSString.

`-valueForKey:` will return an array containing the result of invoking that `-description` method on all its objects. This doesn't seem to be the case here, because `[tmp valueForKey:@"description"]` seems to return a `NSString *` and not an array. I guess `tmp` isn't an array and thus your app crashes.

Without knowing what the JSON data actually is, it's impossible to say what's going wrong here. Please update your question with some example data.

Comment: It says "No visible @interface for NSArray declares the selector 'objectForKey:'"

Comment: Oh well, I didn't notice that you're calling `-valueForKey:` on the `tmp` array. What do you think this code should be doing? I don't get it. I assume you meant to query the dictionary for the object associated with the `@"description"` key. If that's right, change it to `[[res objectForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

Comment: All I'm trying to do is get the *tmp array as a string to be shown in a label.

Comment: The `tmp` array contains a series of strings? Then simply do `[tmp componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

Comment: NSArray *tmp = [results valueForKey:@"temp_f"];
    NSString *tmpstring = [tmp componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    temp.text = tmpstring;

Comment: Please tell me what's inside that array or I won't be able to help you.

Comment: @FabianKreiser Just as a note. If you call `valueForKey:@"description"` in an `NSArray` containing `NSDictionaries` it will **not** return the array's description but an array of all the `description` values of included dictionaries (as expected).

Comment: @Alladinian I know that the collection classes have their own implementation of `-valueForKey:` and that it should return an array with the description of the objects, but the crash indicates that it instead returns a `NSString` instance: `-[__NSCFString componentsJoinedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5680d0`

Answer (score 0):

**description** returns an NSString for all objects that inherit from NSObject. 
Neither NSString nor its ancestors implement **componentsJoinedByString**. 
If you want to use **componentsJoinedByString** you need to send that directly to an NSArray or other collection object that implements that method. 
With nested messaging in Objective-C, you need to be sure what your returned object class is. If you are not sure, unnest your messages so you will see what it is. 
If you cannot be sure in some situation, it is better to unnest messages and verify using some approach like

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(someSelector:)]) {
     // do stuff here
} else {
     // some alternative
}
```